# Find the function that produces the largest output in a n-tree

Tags: haskell

so I have the following tree-like data structure:

```
data Tree = Node (Int -> Int) Int [Tree]
```

Basically, every node consists of a label function `(Int -> Int)`, a label `Int` and a list of sub-trees.  Now I want to write a function, that, when given a Tree and an Int, finds the function that would produce the largest output with the given input.

I am able to find the largest output if I apply the function, but I don't seem to be able to find the associated function.

```
tmax :: Int -> Tree -> Int
tmax l (Node func _ []) = func l
tmax l (Node func _ xs) = max (func l) $ maximum $ map (tmax l) xs
```

This gives me the largest output that can be produced by any of the functions when applied to l.

Some examples of the the intended function:

```
t2 = Node (+1) 1 [Node (+5) 2 [], Node (-3) 7 [], Node (\x -> x*x) 4 []]

          (+1) 1
     /-------|-------\
  (+5) 2   (-3) 7   (\x -> x*x) 4
```

So if I were to apply `tmax 4 t2`, the answer would be `(\x -> x*x)`, because that would deliver the biggest output. If I were to execute `tmax 2 t2`, the output would be `(+5)` because then that would deliver the biggest output. My current function however would only deliver the biggest value, but not the function. So for the first example it would deliver 16, for the second one 7.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear how you intend to use this data structure and what result you want. Please give some more information.

Comment: Added an example of how it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to do it by writing my own implementations of `maximum` and `max` so they return the function and not the value. Then everything worked just fine, thanks!

Comment: very good! Now that you know how it should work, it is time to check out `Data.List.maximumBy`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Write a binary maximum, first.

```
bmax :: Int -> Tree -> Tree -> Tree
bmax l t1@(Node f1 _ _) t2@(Node f2 _ _) | f1 l > f2 l = t1
                                         | otherwise   = t2
```

Then, use recursion to compute the maximum of all the subtrees. You can use a fold for the subtree lists.